# SQL Inserted table trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I run the following select statement inside an insert trigger, is it possible that it will return more than one result?:
DECLARE @variable char(1) = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
If so, then what's the best to handle it?

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve: Every time when the new record is inserted into a table, I want to take the newly inserted ID and insert it into another table(if it doesn't exists).

Thank you!

Comment: It is not only possible but highly likely and such code is simply wrong (because there is a bug waiting to happen).  The correct way to handle it is not to assign values from `inserted` into a variable.  You need more information in your question for a better answer.

Comment: you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: Apart from that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns a **scalar** value, @user3510665 , and a `INSERT` can affect between 1 and ∞ rows. If 2 are more are inserted (which they can and will be) the same issue as assigning values to variables will occur. `inserted` contains a data set, and should be treated as a data set.

Comment: Use `INSERT...SELECT...FROM inserted WHERE NOT EXISTS` or a similar `MERGE` statement to conditionally insert potentially multiple rows from `inserted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
DECLARE @variable char(1) = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
```

You can do something like following:

```
Declare @VarTempTbl as table (id int)

Insert into @VarTempTbl (id)
Select id from inserted
```

So that you can get those values for further processing

Comment: So in the end I guess I still have to loop through a set of data? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Now, I had created Two tables One for Master table and another for When any Insertion happens in that Master table, that entry has to inserted into the another table.

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmployee
(
Id int Primary Key,
Name nvarchar(30),
Gender nvarchar(10),
DepartmentId int
)

CREATE TABLE tblEmployee_New
(
Id int Primary Key,
Name nvarchar(30),
Gender nvarchar(10),
DepartmentId int
)
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_EMPLOYEEDETAILS_AFTEROFINSERT
ON TBLEMPLOYEE
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

TRUNCATE TABLE tblEmployee_New

INSERT INTO TBLEMPLOYEE_NEW(ID, NAME, GENDER, DEPARTMENTID)
SELECT ID, NAME, GENDER, DEPARTMENTID
FROM INSERTED 

END
```

Now Lets try to insert into record into a master table

```
Insert into tblEmployee values (1,'John', 'Male', 3)
Insert into tblEmployee values (2,'Mike', 'Male', 2)
```

It has automatically insert the newly inserted records into the another table.
If your want to remove the Previous records then add a drop Statement in that above Trigger.

Note: You can also use #Temp Table instead of creating a another table('tblEmployee_New')

Kinldy Share your comments

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
Now, how would you do this without truncating the tblEmployee_New table?

Comment: Yes, you can simply comment that Truncate Statement in that Trigger.

If you do like that, your 'tblEmployee_New' contains previous inserted rows also-

Would you need those?

i am using that to take the newly inserted rows only- if you need previous records also then u can comment that Truncate Stmt. @Redskin